# Alternative way of sending array to NodeJS using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

So I've had a lot of problems with sending arrays to NodeJS using AJAX, when sending it with JSON, the error function always gets called (asking why that is has given me no answer that I could use).

So I was wondering if anyone knows a different approach to this, the one that I have right now is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/deposit?steamid=' + steamid,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({arr:items}),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("Tradeoffer has been sent");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Failed to call bot, please inform us about this issue by DM'ing us at https://twitter.com/csgobeararms");
        console.log("Failed to call bot, please inform us about this issue by DM'ing us at https://twitter.com/csgobeararms");
    }
});
```

And on the server side:

```
app.post('/deposit', function(req, res) {
   console.log('Deposit request recieved, info:');
   console.log('STEAM ID: ' + req.query.steamid);
   console.log('ITEMS: ' + req.body.arr);
});
```

So I was wondering if someone could tell me another way of sending an array.

If you can tell me what's wrong with this code, that would be awesome to of course.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser's console? I suspect a CORS issue here.

Comment: Show us the exact array `items` you are trying to send. Also print `data` object that you reveice as a paremeter in the `error` function

Comment: Please show us the error message that you could not use, we will be able to use it.

Comment: Try without stringifying. let it be data: {arr: items}

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I get no errors in browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.js

//nodejs v4.2.6

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
fs.readFile('test.html',function (err, data){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':data.length});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
});
app.post('/deposit', function(req, res) {
   console.log('Deposit request recieved, info:');
   console.log('STEAM ID: ' + req.query.steamid);
   //console.log('ITEMS: ' + req.body.arr);
   res.send({'finish':'finish'});
});

app.listen(3000, function(){    
      console.log('http Express server(worker) listening on port 3000');
});
```

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var steamid = 1;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/deposit?steamid=' + steamid,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({arr:[1,2,3,4]}),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("Tradeoffer has been sent");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Failed to call bot, please inform us about this issue by DM'ing us at https://twitter.com/csgobeararms");
        console.log("Failed to call bot, please inform us about this issue by DM'ing us at https://twitter.com/csgobeararms");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see anything on the backend, and nothing in the console either

Comment: So make sure you are sending a valid json and returning from the api a valid json,Just log this JSON.stringify({arr:items}) before ajax call happens,
 You can check whether a json is valid or not from here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: jsonlint says valid JSON

Comment: I have created your example and everything works fine at my end, See above, I have edited everything

Comment: The arr is still undefined

Answer (score -2):

I think that you listen to the wrong URL in Node. From AJAX you call url: `http://localhost:1337/deposit?steamid=' + steamid,`, but you listen to `'/deposit'` in Node.
You could try using RegExp:

```
app.post(new RegExp('/deposit?steamid=[a-zA-Z0-9]')
```

(assuming that `steamid only contains alphanumerical characters).

Since you're not sending a `GET` request you might as well get rid of the `steamid` parameter in the URL and call `http://localhost:1337/deposit/' + steamid,`; you should then listen to `app.post(new RegExp('/deposit?steamid=[a-zA-Z0-9]')` in Node.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Node takes only the path into account, not the query string.